# Failed to restart mariadb.service: Unit mariadb.service not found

Tags: mysql, mariadb, ubuntu-16.04

In my VPS mariadb running but I cant restart its giving Failed to restart error, my website running perfectly. This is a Ubuntu 16.04 runing with NGINX, MariaDB, Php7.0-fpm.

```
# service mariadb restart
Failed to restart mariadb.service: Unit mariadb.service not found.
```

Mariadb status showing its dead

```
root@ubuntu-2gb-ams2-01:/var/lib# service mariadb status
● mariadb.service
   Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

I can see all database I have

```
root@ubuntu-2gb-ams2-01:/var/lib# mysql -u root -p -e 'show databases'
Enter password:
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| protest            |
+--------------------+
```

I can login and create database without any problem using SSH, can any one please give me clue where I have to check?

Comment: Can you pst the output of `mysql -V`

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/832625/mariadb-not-working-just-after-install-on-ubuntu-16-04

Answer (score 5):

replace **mariadb** to **mysql** and try it.

In my ubuntu16.04, the mariadb.service named mysql.service

> service mysql status

Comment: **In my ubuntu16.04, the mariadb.service named mysql.service** --that made my concept clear

Comment: Unit mysql.service could not be found.